# output select in a file PSQL / POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

How I output select into a file?

I try

```
SELECT * FROM table \g filename
```

but I get “filename: Permission denied”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the file already exists and you have no write permission, or you have no write permission on your current working directory.

Try an absolute path:

```
SELECT * FROM atable \g /writable/directory/filename
```

Comment: it is possible to change the name of the column when I execute a select, type the name of the column is customer_email and wanted by Email

Comment: Sure, use an alias: `SELECT customer_email AS email`.

Comment: `    @classmethod
    def load_view_order_by_email(cls, email):
        with CursorFromConnectionPool() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT product_1, product_2, product_3, product_4, product_5, order_date FROM customer_order WHERE customer_email=%s \g /home/bruno/customer_order.txt', (email,))` is give a error because the \g ?

Comment: This works only with the `psql` client, it is *not* part of SQL.